# Questions on ROS 2 with DDS-Security

Tags: ros2, dds

I'm a student studying ROS 2. I have the following two questions while studying DDS-Security:

1. DDS-Security v1.1 document states, "Secure DDS systems need to co-exist in the same network and, in some cases, interoperate with non-secure DDS systems."
   How does ROS2 with DDS-Security interoperate with regular ROS2 that doesn't have DDS-Security applied? ROS2 with DDS-Security communicates between Pub/Subs based on certificates, so I don't understand how it interoperates with regular ROS2 where no certificates exist.
2. is it absolutely necessary for ROS2 with DDS-Security to interoperate with ROS2 without DDS-Security? Can't they be used separately? I'm curious about real-world use cases.